# Compiling an app using adhoc configuration fails but debug configuration works in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

Please help me figure out the following issue.

When I compile my app using Xcode 5.1.1 using Debug build configuration, it compiles without errors. Build configuration is set here: Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Select Run from the left pane -> Select Info tab from the right pane -> Select Debug in the Build Configuration drop down.

The moment I change build configuration to AdHoc, my app compiles with errors. If I change it back to Debug, the app compiles OK.

All the compiler errors that I'm getting are "ARC Semantic Issue. Multiple methods named 'blah' found with mismatched result...".

Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the code. If you are using different targets you might have a file included twice in the compilation file list. I'd start by cleaning and wiping derived data to make sure you're not linking against old trash that resides in there.

Comment: Post relevant code and the actual, exact error message.

Comment: Do your different configurations have the same ARC settings? (They're under the "Build Settings" section titled "Apple LLVM 5.1 - Language - Objective-C".) You can twirl open the build setting and change it for different configurations. Perhaps Debug and AdHoc are out of sync?

Comment: Here the bit of code that's causing a compiler error: `if ([[TransitionManager instance] count] == 0) { /* do something */ }`. The `instance` method of the `TransitionManager` class returns type `id`. Here the compiler error: **BaseViewController.m:158:9: Multiple methods named 'count' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes.** Xcode also points out the the same `count` method is also defined in NSArray and some other class in my app. I tried deleting derived data, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the cause of a problem. I noticed that the app stopped compiling after I merged a commit from a feature branch. It turns out the commit changed ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file. The working config is below:

`05D1260F10505677008A9AD9 /* AdHoc */ = {
                        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
                        buildSettings = {
+                               ARCHS = "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)";
                                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = YES;
                                CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = Entitlements.plist;`

This is just a GIT diff. The line containing the + was missing from the file in the merged commit.

The merged commit contained this for the Debug configuration, however (the line with -):
`C01FCF4F08A954540054247B /* Debug */ = {
                        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
                        buildSettings = {
-                               ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES;`

I don't really know what this means, but my code compiles again. Will need to do some more digging to understand it better.

Thanks everyone for your help!